# Possibility of memory error?

Tags: python, memory

```
a=raw_input()
prefix_dict = {}
for j in xrange(1,len(a)+1):
    prefix = a[:j]
    prefix_dict[prefix] = len(prefix)
print prefix_dict
```

Is there any possibility of memory error in the above code? This code is running on a server, the server is a quad core Xeon machines running 32-bit Ubuntu (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). For few cases its working and for few its showing memory error. FYI: I do not know the cases that they are testing but inputs are lower case alphabets. Size of input <= 10,000

Comment: Of course. Especially if you allocate a lot of large objects before getting to it.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but in this code, `len(prefix)` will always be equal to `j`. There's no need to do `len(prefix)`.

Comment: I have a question. Can what is read in by raw_input() be made lazy, and how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of memory for just the data alone for that will be 1 + 2 + 3 ... + n-2 + n-1 + n where n is the length of the input, in other words, `len(a)`.  That works out to (n+1) * n/2.  If n is 10,000, this works out to about 50 MB of string data plus however much RAM is used by a python dictionary to store 10,000 entries.  Testing on my OSX box, this seems minimal and indeed if I run this code on it, the process shows 53.9 MB used:

```
str = "a"
d = {}
for i in xrange(10000):
    d[str] = i
    str = str + "a"
```

I don't see anything overtly wrong with your code and when I run it on a string that is 10,000 letters long, it happily spits out about 50mb to output, so something else must be going wrong.

What does `top` show as memory usage for the process?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a smaller piece of code will help:

```
prefix_dict = { a[:j]:j for j in xrange(1, len(a) + 1) }
```

Comment: How so? A couple of bytecode instructions more take a couple of bytes more; clearly that's impossibly small compared to how much data is stored.

Comment: @delnan : also `prefix` as intermediate storage is scrapped. Maybe the garbage collector is not working during the loop and then about 5000*10000 bytes are kept in memory.

Comment: Refcounting is always working and the cycle GC does not care about Python loops. But it doesn't matter, because the strings to which `prefix` refers are still reachable due to `predix_dict`.