# Seeking guidelines for lazy-izing Python data

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

Note: I have edited the original question based on comments and answers.

My question is if a large quantity of Python data is input into a program, how can that data be made lazy, so memory does not overflow?

For example, if a list is built by reading in a file and appending each line or portion of a line to a list, is that list lazy? In other words, can a list be appended to and the list be lazy? Is appending to a list reading the entire file into memory?

I understand that if I wanted to walk through that list, I would write a generator function to keep the access lazy.

What is triggering this question is this recent [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618782/possibility-of-memory-error#comment15385219_11618782)

If this data were coming from a database table with 10M rows, like one of our MySQL daily water meter reads tables, I would not use the mysqldb fetchall() command without knowing how to make the data lazy. Instead, I would read one row at a time.

But what If I did want the contents of that data in memory as a lazy sequence? How would I do it in Python?

Given that I am not presenting source code with a specific problem, the answer I'm looking for is a pointer or pointers to a place in the Python documentation or somewhere else to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be asking for contradictory things. Lazy evaluation means not generating data until you need it, but storing it memory means you need it immediately. You can't store something you haven't generated yet.

Comment: @MarkRansom If appending the file to a list means I want it all in memory, then that is what I want to do. And, it seems like I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of "lazy" code is that the code does not get data until it needs the data.

For example, suppose I am writing a function to copy a text file.  It would not be lazy to read the entire file into memory, then write the entire file.  It also would not be lazy to use the `.readlines()` method to build a list out of all the input lines.  But it would be lazy to read one line at a time and then write each line after reading.

```
# non-lazy
with open(input_fname) as in_f, open(output_fname, "w") as out_f:
    bytes = in_f.read()
    out_f.write(bytes)

# also non-lazy
with open(input_fname) as in_f, open(output_fname, "w") as out_f:
    lines = in_f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        out_f.write(line)

# lazy
with open(input_fname) as in_f, open(output_fname, "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:  # only gets one line at a time
        out_f.write(line) # write each line as we get it
```

To help make your code lazy, Python lets you use "generators".  Functions written using the `yield` statement are generators.  For your database example, you could write a generator that would yield up one row at a time from the database, and then you could write code like this:

```
def db_rows(database_name):
    # code to open the database goes here
    # write a loop that reads rows
        # inside the loop, use yield on each row
        yield row
    # code to close the database goes here

for row in db_rows(database_name):
    # do something with the row
```

Comment: To extend your answer further, if instead of writing the line out, it is appended to a list, is that list lazy?

Comment: No, that list is not lazy.  In my "lazy" example, after we are done writing the line to the output, we no longer keep the line.  We never hold more than one line at a time.  We only *need* one line at a time, so it is not "lazy" to store all the lines in a list.  The "lazy" way, we are using less memory but we are still getting the work done.  Our program is faster, because Python doesn't waste time building a giant list of all lines from the input file, then deleting the list when we are done with it.  We just read one line, use it immediately, and release it.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism in Python for presenting a sequence lazily is [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

> Generators [sic] functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.

Comment: I am currently not able to visualize an example of storing the data once processed through a generator. In other words, I want to process it, place it in memory, and then realize the data as I need it.

Comment: Storing it *is* realizing it. You need to rearchitect what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

A list is almost the opposite of lazy. The best example would be the difference between `range` and `xrange`; `range` creates a list, while `xrange` lazily gives you each number as you need it, using a generator.

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for i in range(2**30):
    total += i

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in range(2**30):
MemoryError
>>> print total
0
>>> for i in xrange(2**30):
    total += i
>>> print total
576460751766552576
```

Many of the places that will take a list will also take a generator in its place. This is so true that Python 3 does away with `xrange` entirely, and uses it to replace the normal `range`.

```
>>> total2 = sum(xrange(2**30))
>>> print total2
576460751766552576
```

It's easy to make your own generator:

```
>>> def myrange(n):
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            yield i
            i += 1
>>> sum(xrange(10))
45
>>> sum(myrange(10))
45
>>> myrange(10)
<generator object myrange at 0x02A2DDA0>
```

And if you do really need a list, that's easy too. But then of course it's no longer lazy.

```
>>> list(myrange(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into generators if you just want something that you can iterate over:

[PEP 255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) contains a lot of relevant info.

Another option, depending on the type of file is the [linecache](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html?highlight=file%20cache#module-linecache) module.

Comment: I'm looking to store it in RAM without realizing it all at once and causing a memory overflow.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I've also added a link to the `linecache` module although I'm not convinced that is what you're looking for either...

Comment: Thanks. linecache reference helpful, and not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> But what If I did want the contents of that data in memory as a lazy sequence?

Here's how you make a lazy sequence: instead of storing the items, generate them on the fly as they are requested, but hide that behind `[]` syntax. I keep forgetting how the SQL API works, so the following should be understood as pseudocode.

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, db_cursor):
        self._cursor = db_cursor

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._cursor.fetch_row(i)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(len(self)):
            yield self[i]

    def __len__(self):
        return self._cursor.number_of_rows()
```

This can be used in many sitations where a `list` can be used, but does not actually store anything. Add caching as needed (depending on the access pattern).